# there are INNER JOIN limits?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

There are a limit to use INNER JOIN?

**Original Query** (Work just fine) I got 77 rows affected

```
    SELECT atendimento.id, atendimento.responsavel, atendimento.ocorrencia, 
           atendimento.idcontrato, cliente.nome as clinome, cliente.id as cliid, 
           atendimento.d_ini, usuario.apelido, tipos.descricao, tipos.id as tip 
      FROM atendimento 
INNER JOIN cliente ON atendimento.cliente=cliente.id 
INNER JOIN usuario ON atendimento.usuario=usuario.id 
INNER JOIN tipos ON atendimento.status=tipos.id 
     WHERE 1=1 AND (atendimento.status=10 OR atendimento.status=11) 
  ORDER BY tipos.id, atendimento.d_ini ASC
```

**New Try:** (Not working very well) it is limited to only 17 rows affected. The result here is the same except for the only 17 rows returned in my query.

```
    SELECT atendimento.id, atendimento.responsavel, atendimento.ocorrencia, 
           atendimento.idcontrato, atend_os.protocolo, atend_os.tecnico, 
           cliente.nome as clinome, cliente.id as cliid, atendimento.d_ini, 
           usuario.apelido, tipos.descricao, tipos.id as tip 
      FROM atendimento 
INNER JOIN atend_os ON atendimento.id=atend_os.protocolo 
INNER JOIN cliente ON atendimento.cliente=cliente.id 
INNER JOIN usuario ON atendimento.usuario=usuario.id 
INNER JOIN tipos ON atendimento.status=tipos.id 
     WHERE 1=1 AND (atendimento.status=10 OR atendimento.status=11) 
  ORDER BY tipos.id, atendimento.d_ini ASC
```

What is going wrong here? does someone know why the result change?

Thanks a lot for any info!

Comment: Please format your queries so that the difference is easier to see.

Comment: @Ponies: apologies for the editing collision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 SELECT atendimento.id, atendimento.responsavel, atendimento.ocorrencia, 
           atendimento.idcontrato, atend_os.protocolo, atend_os.tecnico, 
           cliente.nome as clinome, cliente.id as cliid, atendimento.d_ini, 
           usuario.apelido, tipos.descricao, tipos.id as tip 
      FROM atendimento 
INNER JOIN cliente ON atendimento.cliente=cliente.id 
INNER JOIN usuario ON atendimento.usuario=usuario.id 
INNER JOIN tipos ON atendimento.status=tipos.id 
LEFT JOIN atend_os ON atendimento.id=atend_os.protocolo 
     WHERE 1=1 AND (atendimento.status=10 OR atendimento.status=11) 
  ORDER BY tipos.id, atendimento.d_ini ASC
```

and see how many rows have atend_os.protocolo = NULL

Comment: Gotcha!!! I just did.. thanks. 77 rows affected.  :-)
Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the two queries is that the new query is accessing the `atend_os` table as well.  Thus, any values of `atendimento.cliente` that doesn't also exist as a `cliente.id` is being filtered out.

An `INNER JOIN` requires that the value exist in both tables or the row is discarded.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this table atend_os  does not contain a record for every atendimento. Perhaps you need a left join?